# Webpack в Laravel

Tags: laravel, webpack, phpstorm

**Webpack** при команде `run watch` собирает **CSS** из **SCSS** около 1 минуты. Ошибок никаких нет. **SCSS** прост, без замудреных просчетов.

P.S.
Работа происходит в связке **Phpstorm Laravel Webpack**

Comment: 1 ) В чём ваш вопрос? 2) Шторм каким образом к вебпаку? 3) Если вы что то спрашиваете, то было бы неплохо увидеть конфиг

Comment: Я на всякий случай указал связку в которой происходит работа над проектом.
Вопрос в возможной причине  долгой компиляции.
Конфиг, Вы имеете ввиду package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался.
Отключил перезапись следующим образом:url()

**В файле Webpack.mix.js к строке:**

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

**Добавил:**

```
.options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });
```

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix)